# Jquery with dynamic paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im doing a school work with Jquery and I just want to know if its possible and how to do the following:
Page A has the following : external JS file that has the function to allow a user to enter some text and then when they press the submit button that text is automatically put as the paragraph text as ive use JS to get the element and replace the text using innerhtml.

External JS file:

```
 function grabText() {
     var grabThePara = document.getElementById("firstP").value;
     var intoParagraph = document.getElementById("pOne").innerHTML = grabThePara;
 }
```

HTML FILE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="firstP" name="firstP">
    <br />
    <p id="pOne">Static works fine -- > this is the static</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="grabText()" value="Submit">
    <a href="JSPanel.html">GO to JD Panel</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Page B has the Jquery part, this has the code that will grab the text from the Page A's first paragrpah called ID pOne, it gets the text without an issue if its STATIC input but the moment you use as described previous by using the textbox and dynamically changing the text of the paragraph the page A does the change but Page B still shows the static text input, not the new dynamic changes that occurred after input-ed into the textbox and submitted. I will show code.

Page B code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <a href="adminPanel.html">Change the text again</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "adminPanel.html",
            success: function (printIt) {
                var html = jQuery('<p>').html(printIt);
                var grabIt = html.find("p#pOne").html();
                var sendItToParaOne = document.getElementById("paraOne").innerHTML = grabIt;
            }
        });
    </script>
    <p id="paraOne"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for my English i know its not the best. thanks for taking the time in reading my issue and any helps is appreciated

Thanks again!

M

Comment: the dynamic content (which u added in PAGE A) won't be shown (in PAGE B) because you haven't saved it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your data somewhere. If you don't want to work with a database, you can use HTML 5 web storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Furthermore, looking at your external JS file, you might want to have a look at jQuery selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing yourself by thinking that pages are able to talk to each other. Your page A has to send the changes to the server, but the server also has to be programmed to listen to those changes in server code like PHP or ASP.NET. Only then can page B get the changes made by page A.